# Image list with differents <li> height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-lists

I have simple list of images where each `<li>` element has the same static height forced by `.container` inside.
However selected element can be 2 (or 3) times higher

I was trying to make it by using `display:inline-block` but selected element is pushing next line lower
http://jsfiddle.net/HedZK/1/

or `float:left` which working a bit better but not enaught, some elements still are pushed lower
http://jsfiddle.net/HedZK/2/

Is there a way to do it correctly?

I dont want to use `position:absolute` neither `<table>` because it will crash responsive design

Comment: Do you mean like giving the images an absolute height and width?

Comment: Also, do you realize you spelled "container" wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to solve this using css only. You should look on some js-based solution like http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: I took into account this way, also http://gridster.net/
but I would like to save additional loading time
Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

I think please check you code at under lest at one palce it says:

```
<div class="container" style=" height: 200px ">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
```

I think  **height: 200px** is causing issue. Remove **height: 200px**